# why i am getting "Apply Label" field inside my new lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, retention, retention-policy

I create a new custom list inside our SharePoint online site collection, and i noted that i am getting a field named "Apply label", as follow:-

[image: applylabel]

and inside the list setting i got this :-

[image: applylabel2]

I know those are retention policies, but i did not specify any for our new list.. is this something that have been defined on the organization level for example?

Second question, can we hide this field for this specific list only?

Thanks